# Why is "no crate_relative in serve" when rust rocket_contrib?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-rocket

I'm trying to learn some rust by my usual method of flailing around and running examples.

This page on the rust_contrib api docs makes me think I can serve static files https://api.rocket.rs/master/rocket_contrib/serve/struct.StaticFiles.html like this...

```
use rocket_contrib::serve::StaticFiles;
use rocket_contrib::serve::crate_relative;
```

...

```
fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/content", StaticFiles::from(crate_relative!("content")))
        .mount("/", routes![index])
        .mount("/api", routes![hello, new_book])
        .register(catchers![not_found]) 
        .attach(Template::fairing())
        .launch();
}
```

Instead the compiler barks at me...

```
    error[E0432]: unresolved import `rocket_contrib::serve::crate_relative`
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 | use rocket_contrib::serve::crate_relative;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `crate_relative` in `serve`
```

Cargo.toml looks like this...

```
[package]
name = "rocket-web"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Nunya B. Znas <dontworry@bout.it>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.5"
serde = {version = "1.0", features = ["derive"]}

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "0.4.5"
features = ["handlebars_templates", "tera_templates"]
```

What have I done to offend the rust gods?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs you are looking at are for Rocket's *master* branch, which currently represents the yet-to-be-released 0.5 version. Rocket version 0.4.5 does not have `crate_relative`.

For a workaround, you can see how the [0.4 docs](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket_contrib/serve/struct.StaticFiles.html) say to do it:

```
use rocket_contrib::serve::StaticFiles;

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/", StaticFiles::from(concat!(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"), "/static")))
        .launch();
}
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you! Some day I'll be cool enough for rocket master.